# An incompatible version 1.1.30 of the APR based Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat requires version 1.1.32

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-14.04, bitnami, apr

I'm using AWS with AMI from bitnami:
bitnami-tomcatstack-8.0.15-0-dev-linux-ubuntu-14.04.1-x86_64-hvm-ebs (ami-486d5c55)

It's packed with ubuntu 14.04.1 and tomcat 8.0.15. And 2 days it was working fine. But one day it just stop working after restart. And now I have 503 Service Unavailable and in catalina log:

```
SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init An incompatible version 1.1.30 of the APR based Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat requires version 1.1.32
```

How I can upgrade this library in Ubuntu ?

Comment: That library isn't actually required, it just enhances performance. If you check back to older logs you will probably find you were getting that message even while the website was working.